# Java Array Char And String Difference In Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

While making up some arrays I noticed that

```
char[] javaArray = {'j','a','v','a'};
```

prints out

```
java
```

but

```
String[] javaStringArray = {"j","a","v","a"};
```

only prints the stack location. I know char and String are both very different, but how come the JVM knows to output chars for the first and only a stack location for the second?

I am using IntelliJ and the command `System.out.println(javaArray);`

Comment: Where does `char[] javaArray = {'j','a','v','a'}` print `java`?

Comment: how are you printing?

Comment: Rather than tacking on a vital detail the usage of `println` to the end, it should be prominently featured towards the beginning.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This happens because `PrintStream` has a special override for `char[]`, but it lacks such overrides for `String[]` and other array types:

[`PrintStream.println(char[] x)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(char[]))

If you call `toString()` on `javaArray` when printing, the results would look similar to what you get when you print `String[]`:

```
char[] javaArray = {'j','a','v','a'};
System.out.println(javaArray.toString()); // Prints something like [C@1540e19d
```

Comment: Didn't know this existed...!

Comment: @ErnestKiwele Neither did I - the result came as a surprise to me, so I had to look it up.

Comment: good explanation!!